# Does anyone know about the ring diagram technique and Helioseismic and Magnetic Imager pipeline?

Tags: the-sun, data-analysis, space-telescope

I'm working on the ring diagram technique and pipeline for the Solar Dynamics Observatory's [Helioseismic and Magnetic Imager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_Dynamics_Observatory#Helioseismic_and_Magnetic_Imager_(HMI)) or HMI, but I didn't find much about the details about how it works or how to obtain the data.

I know that all starts with measuring [Dopplergrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dopplergraph) and then doing something call Postel's projection, then the apodization, then the 3D Fourier transform to obtain the 3D power spectra where there are 2 forms of adjust to each ring separately (FITSC and FITSF, both done by the HMI's pipeline).

I need more details about how all this process is done, does anyone know? Or could indicate me some references?

Comment: It isn't clear (to me) what your question is about

Comment: It's about heilioseismology, this tecnique is used to determine subsurface flows in sun. And HMI is the satellite where all the data comes from

Comment: I've added some information back into your question, please feel free to edit further and Welcome to Stack Exchange!